# Firebug page speed warning: enable compression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compression, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing some nitpicky seo and I am worried about firebug showing that my bundled and minifed css files are not compressed, I am using action filter to append gzip header, but I don't know why it is not working for minified/bundled css and js files?

Here is filter:

```
  public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

            string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }

            response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        }
    }
```

I register it in Application_Start() so i don't have to do it on each controller:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CompressFilter());

RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

And I even have this in config:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Headers are correct for views but nothing for css and js.. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to use IIS 7 compression there is no need for that CompressFilter, urlCompression settings should be enough. If your css are served trough ScriptResourceHandler then you should set compression for that also (note that in this example caching is enabled to):

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  ...
</configuration>
```

And just a note, ISA Proxy server strips gzip from Accept-Encoding request header by default, so the ISA can scan the content for malicious data, maybe some other proxy / firewall software do the same thing.

Comment: Well I tried your code but unfortunetly it doesn't seem to work, maybe it's because script and css gets minified/bundled by mvc4.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked MVC 4 tag, maybe, I didn't use MVC 4